# Images are broken after uploading them on 'detail_page'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

After uploading pictures to my webpage (local), it adds a picture to the database, it adds a picture to my media dir, BUT on the webpage, it appears broken.

`settings.py`:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/uploaded/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../media_root')
```

`views.py`:

```
class MovieImageUpload(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = MovieImageForm

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super().get_initial()
        initial['user'] = self.request.user.id
        initial['movie'] = self.kwargs['movie_id']
        return initial

    def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
        movie_id = self.kwargs['movie_id']
        movie_detail_url = reverse(
            'core:MovieDetail',
            kwargs={'pk': movie_id})
        return redirect(
            to=movie_detail_url)

    def get_success_url(self):
        movie_id = self.kwargs['movie_id']
        movie_detail_url = reverse(
            'core:MovieDetail',
            kwargs={'pk': movie_id})
        return movie_detail_url


class MovieDetail(DetailView):
    queryset = Movie.objects.all_with_related_persons_and_score()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ctx['image_form'] = self.movie_image_form()
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            vote = Vote.objects.get_vote_or_unsaved_blank_vote(
                movie=self.object,
                user=self.request.user
            )
            if vote.id:
                vote_form_url = reverse(
                    'core:UpdateVote',
                    kwargs={
                        'movie_id': vote.movie.id,
                        'pk': vote.id})
            else:
                vote_form_url = (
                    reverse(
                        'core:CreateVote',
                        kwargs={
                            'movie_id': self.object.id}
                    )
                )
            vote_form = VoteForm(
                instance=vote)
            ctx['vote_form'] = vote_form
            ctx['vote_form_url'] = \
                vote_form_url
        return ctx

    def movie_image_form(self):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return MovieImageForm()
        return None
```

`models.py`:

```
def movie_directory_path_with_uuid(
        instance, filename):
    return '{}/{}.{}'.format(
        instance.movie_id,
        uuid4(),
        filename.split('.')[-1]
    )


class MovieImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=movie_directory_path_with_uuid)
    uploaded = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True)
    movie = models.ForeignKey(
        'Movie', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

`forms.py`:

```
class MovieImageForm(forms.ModelForm):

    movie = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        widget=forms.HiddenInput,
        queryset=Movie.objects.all(),
        disabled=True
    )
    user = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        widget=forms.HiddenInput,
        queryset=get_user_model().objects.all(),
        disabled=True,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = MovieImage
        fields = ('image', 'user', 'movie')
```

`movie_detail.html`:

```
<ul class="movie-image list-inline" >
    {% for i in object.movieimage_set.all %}
      <li class="list-inline-item" >
        <img src="{{ i.image.url }}" >
      </li >
    {% endfor %}
</ul >
```

Everything works well, except for showing the image. It displays a broken icon. As for `urls.py`, I just added `MEDIA_FILE_PATHS` to my `urlpatterns` variable.

Comment: Can you share the various settings file paths and the urls being generated on the detail page when they are broken?

Comment: Can you share your urls.py

Comment: Also please make sure you are not using debug = False, if you are then it will not serve your images or static files (any you see may be from cache, just a quick check)

Comment: Lol, it was all about DEBUG. Thank you! I used DEBUG = False, and did not check that before. But what about production? If I want to deploy my project somewhere, I need to set DEBUG=False. So how could it serve my static files or images than?